# Unable to locate element on the Frame (selenium c#)

Tags: sitecore-client, automation

I am trying to automate Sitecore using  Selenium (C#).

More details about the automations steps:
Scenario to automate:

1. Login to Sitecore with admin privileges.
2. After logging in, select Content Editor.
3. Next step is to create a home page under a desired location in content tree.
4. Select Presentation Tab > Details .
5. Next Select Final Layout.

I am unable to locate Final layout element as it is present on different frame/Dialog.

I have tried switching on to the frame but does not seem to work. Any help is appreciated!!!

The HTML content:

```
<iframe id="scContentIframeId0" frameborder="0" scrolling="auto" class="ui-dialog-content ui-widget-content ui-dialog-normal" src="/sitecore/shell/default.aspx?xmlcontrol=LayoutDetails&amp;id=%7B110D559F-DEA5-42EA-9C1C-8A5DF7E70EF9%7D&amp;la=en&amp;vs=1" style="width: auto; min-height: 0px; max-height: none; height: 600px;">
    <form>
        <div class=aspnethidden></div>
        <div class=scFlexColumnContainer scStretch></div>
        <div class=scFormDialogHeader></div>
        <div class=DialogHeader></div>
        <div class=scFlexContent scFormDialogContent></div>
        <div class=scStretchAbsolute scDialogContentContainer>
            <div class=scTabstrip>
                <span id=Tabs_tab_1>

                </span>
            </div>
        </div>
        '
        '
        '
    </form>
</iframe>
```

Comment: Can you post your Selenium test c# code?

Comment: //SelectContentEditor
 WebDriver.FindElementX(By.XPath("//img[@src='/temp/iconcache/apps/48x48/pencil.png']")).Click();
//Navigate to Presentation Tab
             WebDriver.FindElementX(By.XPath("//*[@id='RibbonCB15EFC306094C63890E049AD96F3F51_Nav_PresentationStrip']")).Click();
 //Click on Details Panel
             WebDriver.FindElementX(By.XPath("//*[@title='View and edit the layout details for the selected item.']")).Click();
 Thread.Sleep(1000)
 //Click on Final Layout
             WebDriver.SwitchTo().Frame(WebDriver.FindElementX(By.XPath("//iframe[@id='scContentIframeId0']")));

Comment: I am unable to switch to the frame and select an element span id ='Tabs_tab_1'

Comment: There are 2 iframes on the page. You need to switch to the parent iframe first (`jqueryModalDialogsFrame`) and then to the child iframe (`scContentIframeId0`). See the answer below.

Answer (score 1):

Your code doesn't work because `Layout Details` iframe is in another iframe (`jqueryModalDialogsFrame`).

Try the code below:

```
WebDriver.FindElement(By.XPath("//a[@title='Content Editor']")).Click(); 
WebDriver.FindElement(By.XPath("//*[contains(@id,'Nav_PresentationStrip')]")).Click(); 
WebDriver.FindElement(By.XPath("//*[@title='View and edit the layout details for the selected item.']")).Click();
WebDriver.SwitchTo().Frame(WebDriver.FindElement(By.Id("jqueryModalDialogsFrame")));
WebDriver.SwitchTo().Frame(WebDriver.FindElement(By.Id("scContentIframeId0")));
WebDriver.FindElement(By.Id("Tabs_tab_1")).Click();
```